# Anchor points not working when main container is set to position fixed(needed for Linear Interpolation)

Tags: next.js, scroll

So after implementing a Linear Interpolation for a smooth scroll momentum effect, I realized that my anchor points stopped working, and after looking at the code, I realized that "the reason" is the position fixed on the container. So My structure looks like...

[image]

So by removing the position fixed on the container, the anchor points work again, however suddenly I got a huge extra space at the bottom of the page that doesn't happen with the position fixed. I'm not sure if the issue is actually the position fixed, just because I saw an example that is using a library for softing the scrolling, but the guy have a position fixed menu and a container fixed too, so I am not sure anymore. Is my first time doing something like this, so any advice would be great.

A sample sandbox can be found [on here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stoic-davinci-rz4mr7)